# hdf5 dependencies trying to install netcdf4

Tags: python-2.7, pip, centos7, hdf5, netcdf4

I am trying to install NetCDF4 via pip on a CentOS 7 system running Python 2.7. The following HDF5 packages have already been installed via yum:

```
[user@host]$ rpm -qa | grep hdf5
hdf5-openmpi-1.8.12-12.el7.x86_64
hdf5-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
```

Despite the packages being installed, I still encounter this error trying to install hdf5:

```
[user@host]$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
.
.
.
Collecting netCDF4>=1.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/0d/caa957cc1b42b718ce4b9b3e849e6f7aa99faad2d522d8f2d7a33500fba0/netCDF4-1.5.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cOs19I/netCDF4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cOs19I/netCDF4/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cOs19I/netCDF4/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'hdf5' found
    reading from setup.cfg...
    
        HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
    checking /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/include
    checking /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/Library/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/Library/include
    checking /home/ooiui/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /home/ooiui/include
    checking /usr/local/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /usr/local/include
    checking /sw/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /sw/include
    checking /opt/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /opt/include
    checking /opt/local/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /opt/local/include
    checking /usr/include ...
    hdf5 headers not found in /usr/include
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cOs19I/netCDF4/setup.py", line 425, in <module>
        _populate_hdf5_info(dirstosearch, inc_dirs, libs, lib_dirs)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cOs19I/netCDF4/setup.py", line 366, in _populate_hdf5_info
        raise ValueError('did not find HDF5 headers')
    ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

In the past, when I installed NetCDF4 on CentOS 6, I didn't have to make any special tweaks. Has something changed that requires additional prep? Thanks in advance.

Thanks to phd, I had the HDF5 headers installed and set the HDF5_DIR environment variable to /include to reflect the install location. Now I seem to be running into a similar roadblock with NetCDF4 itself:

```
Collecting netCDF4>=1.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/0d/caa957cc1b42b718ce4b9b3e849e6f7aa99faad2d522d8f2d7a33500fba0/netCDF4-1.5.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l853Xs/netCDF4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l853Xs/netCDF4/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l853Xs/netCDF4/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'hdf5' found
    reading from setup.cfg...
    checking /usr/include ...
    HDF5 library version: 1.8.12 headers found in /usr/include
    HDF5 library version: 1.8.12 found in /usr
    
    NETCDF4_DIR environment variable not set, checking standard locations..
    checking /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279 ...
    checking /home/ooiui/miniconda2/envs/ooiui279/Library ...
    checking /home/ooiui ...
    checking /usr/local ...
    checking /sw ...
    checking /opt ...
    checking /opt/local ...
    checking /usr ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-l853Xs/netCDF4/setup.py", line 441, in <module>
        raise ValueError('did not find netCDF version 4 headers')
    ValueError: did not find netCDF version 4 headers
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

We are trying to install NetCDF4 via pip per the requirements.txt file, but it appears to be failing on missing NetCDF4 headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers

The error means there is no development files. You have the library but not headers. Install:

```
yum install hdf5-devel
```

Comment: Thank you, phd. I've installed the HDF5 headers but now have reached a point where the install is failing on NetCDF4 headers. The error message is above.

Comment: Perhaps `yum install netcdf-devel`; see https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/netcdf-devel-4.3.3.1-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: installing netcdf-devel did indeed get us past that hurdle in the pip install. Thank you! We hadn't installed either the hdf5-devel or netcdf-devel packages ahead of time because we hadn't done so with our previous CentOS 6 instances.

Answer (score 0):

The development installs are worth trying. For **ubuntu**, I had the same HDF5_DIR error, and the following resolved

`sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev`